# How the remove the yellow bar for "strong password" for SecureFields in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am new to SwiftUI and am trying out the SecureFields now.
I am using two SecureFields in one VStack and for some reason when I use the iOS keyboard they show this yellow bar with a strong password. Is there any way of removing this "strong password" yellow bar?

[image: Showing the issue]

Code:

```
 VStack(spacing: 0) {
                if showFirst {
                    TextField(placeholderTextFirst, text: $inputFirst)
                        .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .light
                            ? invalidFirst ? .red
                            : color : invalidFirst ? .red : .white)
                        .padding()
                        .placeholder(when: inputFirst.isEmpty) {
                            Text(placeholderTextFirst)
                                .foregroundColor(placeholderColor)
                                .padding()
                        }
                } else {
                    SecureField(placeholderTextFirst, text: $inputFirst)
                        .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .light
                            ? invalidFirst ? .red
                            : color : invalidFirst ? .red : .white)
                        .padding()
                        .placeholder(when: inputFirst.isEmpty) {
                            Text(placeholderTextFirst)
                                .foregroundColor(placeholderColor)
                                .padding()
                        }
                }
                if showSecond {
                    TextField(placeholderTextSecond, text: $inputSecond)
                        .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .light
                            ? invalidSecond ? .red
                            : color : invalidSecond ? .red : .white)
                        .padding().ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard, edges: .bottom)
                        .placeholder(when: inputSecond.isEmpty) {
                            Text(placeholderTextSecond).foregroundColor(placeholderColor)
                                .padding()
                        }
                } else {
                    SecureField(placeholderTextSecond, text: $inputSecond)
                        .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .light
                            ? invalidSecond ? .red
                            : color : invalidSecond ? .red : .white)
                        .padding().ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard, edges: .bottom)
                        .placeholder(when: inputSecond.isEmpty) {
                            Text(placeholderTextSecond).foregroundColor(placeholderColor)
                                .padding()
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Found the fix myself just add:

```
.textContentType(.oneTimeCode)
```

Comment: By doing this, you're telling the SecureField that it's a one time code. Like a 6 digit code that gets texted to the user. So iOS won't give password suggestions to your users and it won't try to auto fill it if your user has a password manager. So yes, it fixes it visually, but it's not really the correct way to treat a password field. Maybe that's what you're going for though.. I guess you didn't specify in the question.